# Can't solve error: "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected"

Tags: iphone

I have upgrade my phone to 4.1 beta version, and I'm using xCode 3.2.2. But it keeps complaining that the version of iPhone OS does not match version of iPhone OS support development with the installation of iphone SDK. So does this match it has to be xCode 3.2.3 and above for it to match?

Answer (score 2):

Your SDK must be greater than or equal to the version in your iOS device.

It is fine to use a 4.1 SDK to build for 3.2.x or earlier, you just have to make sure deployment target is set to the minimum iOS version you want to run the code on.

Answer (score 0):

You need Xcode 4 beta. I just had the same issue with 4.0.2 and xcode 3.2.3.

Comment: I don't believe you need a new Xcode, just a new SDK. For example, SDK 4.1 beta 3 is required to build for iOS 4.1 beta 3 - and by default it comes with Xcode 3.2.4.